# Is there a way to set the recursion limit to infinite in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was trying to make a simple program that would calculate the sum of the harmonic series and then print the results. But then the recursion limit stops it from going on.

Here is the program:

```
def harm_sum(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    else: 
return (1 / n) + (harm_sum(n - 1))

x = 1
while True:
    print(x, harm_sum(x))
    x += 1
```

I want the program to keep on running despite the recursion limit is there a way to do that?

Comment: This is asking for a segfault.

Comment: Try rewriting your tail recursion as a loop.

Comment: Infinite? No. Other languages can optimize for infinite recursion (if the programmer does it correctly) but Python can't.

Comment: @mypetlion python *doesn't* optimize tail calls, but I don't think there is any reason why it couldn't in principle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Direct answer**: No, you cannot disable the stack limit; it's there to avoid using up all the available stack space, which would crash your run without any Traceback information.

Also, note that it's not *possible* to have an infinite stack size: each stack frame occupies RAM; you'll eventually run out and crash the system.

**Workaround**: If you can handle a hard crash, then simply use `sys.setrecursionlimit` to set it beyond the physical limits of your system (which are system-dependent).

**Real solution**: as Juan already noted, you can simply re-code your recursion as a loop.